# default colorbar for matplotlib

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib, default

I'd like to change the global default colorbar for all graphics commands in Python matplotlib. This is similar to [this question about changing the default colorbar in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034903/how-do-you-set-a-custom-default-colormap-in-matlab). Here [there is already a pythonic solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437689/matplotlib-globally-set-number-of-ticks-x-axis-y-axis-colorbar), but that solution requires making a plot in order for the change to take effect. Is there a way to set the default before the first plot is made?

Putting the following in `~/.pythonrc` seems like it ought to work, but it does not:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = plt.cm.bwr
```

Furthermore, I'd like to set the default to something from the `colorbrewer2mpl` package, not just a pre-existing matplotlib option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An iPython specific solution:

Put a .py file (any name, see the README in this folder) in `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/` with the following:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import brewer2mpl
cmap=brewer2mpl.get_map('RdBu', 'diverging', 7).mpl_colormap
plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = cmap.name
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution that does work is to [customize the matplotlibrc file](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html)

Find it:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()
```

Edit it:

```
image.cmap: bwr
```

However, this method only lets me select default named colorbars, not, for example, [ColorBrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/) colorbars available via the `colorbrewer2mpl` package.

Comment: In mpl a colorbar is something else. You can add your own colormaps to `_cm.py` in your mpl directory and then change your rc file.

Comment: @RutgerKassies, Could you post and example of how to add a new colormap to _cm.py? I can not understand the used format